# i cant apply another color after applying original color effect on imageview

Tags: android

I have made paint related application..  In that app,im trying to apply original image effect same like we paint on the image..
but the problem occurs when i paint another color after applying original color to the image. i cant apply any other color to image once original color is been applied. i have taken two imageviews:one to load image and another to paint on image.i will be thankfull  if anyone can help me out. thanks in advance.
here is my code..

```
public class Draw extends Activity implements OnTouchListener
{
    ImageView imagesave, imagepaint, clear, back, done, cayan, purple, green, red, yellow, pink, orange, blue,
              gray, violet, rose, gold, chocolate;
    Button original;
    SeekBar s1;
    RelativeLayout rltop;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    Canvas canvas;
    Paint paint;
    float downx = 0, downy = 0, upx = 0, upy = 0;

    int a, r, g, b;
    int pixel;
    int x, y;
    int h = Glob.bmp.getWidth();
    int w = Glob.bmp.getHeight();

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        try
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

            setContentView(R.layout.draw);
            imagesave = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagesave);
            imagesave.setImageBitmap(Glob.bmp);

            s1 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
            done = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivdone);
            clear = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivclear);
            back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivback);
            rltop = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rltop);
            original = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.original);
            cayan = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.cayan);
            purple = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.purple);
            green = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.green);
            red = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.red);
            yellow = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.yellow);
            pink = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.pink);
            orange = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.orange);
            blue = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.blue);
            gray = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.gray);
            violet = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.violet);
            rose = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.rosegold);
            gold = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.gold);
            chocolate = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.chocolate);
            imagepaint = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imagepaint);

            Display currentDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            float dw = currentDisplay.getWidth();
            float dh = currentDisplay.getHeight();
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            paint = new Paint();
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setDither(true);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(10f);
            paint.setStrokeMiter(50);
            imagepaint.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            imagepaint.setOnTouchListener(this);
            imagepaint.setAlpha(150);

            clear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    bitmap.eraseColor(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT);
                }
            });

            done.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    rltop = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rltop);
                    rltop.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

                    Bitmap bitmap = rltop.getDrawingCache();

                    Glob.bmp1 = bitmap;
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Show.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });

            back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });

            s1.setMax(255);
            s1.setProgress((10));

            s1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0)
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0)
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress,boolean arg2) 
                {
                    paint.setStrokeWidth(progress);
                }
            });

            original.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
                }

            });
            cayan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                }
            });

            purple.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    paint.setColor(Color.rgb(153, 50, 205));
                }
            });

            green.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                }
            });

            red.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
                }
            });

            yellow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                }
            });

            pink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    paint.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 204));
                }
            });

            orange.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    paint.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 69, 0));
                }
            });

            blue.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                }
            });

            gray.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    paint.setColor(Color.rgb(169,169,169));
                }
            });

            violet.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    paint.setColor(Color.rgb(216, 191, 216));
                }
            });

            rose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    paint.setColor(Color.rgb(246, 217, 213));
                }
            });
            gold.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    paint.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 215, 0));
                }
            });
            chocolate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    paint.setColor(Color.rgb(85, 42, 12));
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        try {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                downx = event.getX();
                downy = event.getY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                upx = event.getX();
                upy = event.getY();
                canvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, paint);
                imagepaint.invalidate();
                downx = upx;
                downy = upy;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                upx = event.getX();
                upy = event.getY();
                canvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, paint);
                imagepaint.invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }

    void onbackpressed() 
    {
        try
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thnx but,Still have poblem wid this.. can u plz provide an example **@Alex M**